# Puma: Status file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3, puma

I am trying to deploy a Rails application with Capistrano. I had an issue of `bundler: command not found: pumactl`, which I seem to have resolved by adding the puma gem to my Gemfile outside of the `:development` group.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'semantic-ui-sass', github: 'doabit/semantic-ui-sass'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'prawn-rails', '0.1.1'
gem 'fastimage', '1.6.6'
gem 'mini_magick', '4.0.4'
gem 'carrierwave', '0.10.0'
gem 'puma', '2.11.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capistrano', '3.3.5'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', '0.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '1.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '1.1.4'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', '0.8.5'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Now when I attempt to `cap production deploy:initial --trace` (or `cap production deploy --trace`), I get the following output:

```
...
INFO [7314ca0d] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/myuser/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state restart as myuser@mydomain.com
DEBUG [7314ca0d] Command: cd /home/myuser/apps/myapp/releases/20150213082155 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec pumactl -S /home/myuser/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state restart
DEBUG [7314ca0d]    Status file not found: /home/myuser/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state
DEBUG [7314ca0d]    
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as myuser@mydomain.com: Exception while executing as myuser@mydomain.com: Exception while executing as myuser@mydomain.com: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
...
```

I was attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/ttrhow/deploying-rails-app-using-nginx-puma-and-capistrano-3).

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.3.5'

set :user, 'myuser'
set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:myuser/myapp-rails.git'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'
set :keep_releases, 2
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, false

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

This problem usually results from previously attempting to use a different gem `capistrano-puma` as opposed to `capistrano3-puma`. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/issues/83).

In my case, I had to `gem uninstall capistrano-puma` even though it was not included in my Gemfile. Thanks to [@seuros](https://github.com/seuros) for the help.